# How can I create a new annotation?

Tags: java, spring

How can I create a new annotation based on a Spring `@Service` annotation or `@Component`?

I want just to change the name for a more semantic use: for example change the name to `@TransactionelService`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create your own annotation (e.g. `@MyComponent`) annotated with the corresponding spring annotation. For example:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
public @interface MyComponent {
}
```

Comment: +1 I would use `@Service` instead of `@Component` as user will be using it for service layer. `@Service` internally uses `@Component`.

Comment: Then instead of the `@Component` annotation you can use `@Service` annotation to create new annotation like `@Service`.

Answer (score 0):

Meta-annotations:

Annotations which can be used to annotate other annotations.

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Service
@Transactional(timeout = 60)
public @interface MyTranscationalService{
}
```

--this recognizes the above code and scans the below code also

and we can use MyTranscationalService as annotation for other classes

```
@MyTranscationalService
public class TransferImpl implements TransferService{
}
```